# Which python.snippets file will be called?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, snippets

There are two `python.snippets` in vim-snippets folder:

```
debian@debian:~/.vim/bundle$ ls  vim-snippets/snippets | grep python
python.snippets
debian@debian:~/.vim/bundle$ ls  vim-snippets/UltiSnips | grep python
python.snippets
```

1. Which one will be called when I type a abbreviation in vim?
2. Which `python.snippets` should I write my customized snippets into?

They contains different grammar.
It is as below in vim-snippets/snippets/python.snippets:

```
snippet if
    if ${1:condition}:
        ${0:${VISUAL}}
```

It is as below in vim-snippets/UltiSnips/python.snippets:

```
snippet ifee "If / Elif / Else" b
if ${1:condition}:
    ${2:${VISUAL:pass}}
elif ${3:condition}:
    ${4:pass}
else:
    ${5:pass}
endsnippet
```

3. Which one is the correct grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two formats of snippets that Ultisnips supports: (1) SnipMate snippets, and (2) UltiSnips snippets. Files containing SnipMate snippets (1) would go in the `snippets` directory, while files containing UltiSnips snippets (2) would go in the `UltiSnips` directory.

[UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) was designed to be a drop-in replacement for [SnipMate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim) (see `:h UltiSnips-snipMate`), enabling one to migrate over to UltiSnips with SnipMate snippets. In particular, support for SnipMate is controlled by the option `g:UltiSnipsEnableSnipMate`.
If it is `1`, both SnipMate and UltiSnips snippets will be used. And if it is `0`, only Ultisnips snippets will be used.

As for your second question, you can use either, but note that their formats differ [(snipmate format)](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim/blob/master/doc/snipMate.txt#L40) [(UltiSnips format)](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L588). Personally, I would recommend the UltiSnips format. That is, place `python_*.snippets` in the `UltiSnips` directory. Actually, instead of `vim-snippets/UltiSnips/python.snippets`, you should use place the file in a custom directory , that is, `.vim/UltiSnips/python.snippets`. You should also read [`:h UltiSnips-how-snippets-are-loaded`](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L516) for more details of which filenames are supported.